# Are there any items to boost exp gain?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

Are there any items, accessories or abilities which boost the rate at which a unit gains experience through combat?

I often find with new units I summon, that I need to boost them quickly. Other than using Cactuars to give the unit experience, are there any equippable items which give an experience boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unit Medius (3 to 6 Stars FFBE Unit) Has a [Growth Egg as Trust Master](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Growth_Egg) reward.
Its Description says:

> Whoever is fortunate enough to acquire the growth egg will earn battle
>   experience at a much faster rate, as well as quickly gain knowledge of
>   magical spells and abilities.

I haven't mastered it myself, so I might have just traded one grinding for another.
Other than that I have seen nothing so far.

*Edit*
The [trust master reward for Nine is Action](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Action), which boosts EXP by 50%.

In the Year 1 Anniversary event, there is a reward item '[Anniversary Ring](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Anniversary_Ring)' which has Exp x1.3 bonus.
[image: Anniversary ring]

Answer (score -3):

The two most common are Medius' TMR Growth Egg (an accessory, meaning you can wear 2, and yes their exp boost stack) and Nine's TMR Action which is a materia meaning you can use up to 4 at once.

There's are others but those are by far the most accessible.  Here's a link containing more information (and other items as well)

https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/8n7rgz/exp_boosts_and_where_to_use_them/